# Copy file from one folder to another folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I am working on website in which i want to copy the file from my application folder to other folder on same server (But this folder is out of my application folder i.e. my application on C driver and the destination folder is on D drive).Is this possible using any functionality of Asp.Net?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try? One line of code is all it would take to test it.

Comment: @Oded, I am not getting will you please explain.

Comment: Seems a bit harsh to downgrade. I've seen worse

Comment: @gofor.net whenever you ask any question please try that you put your code efforts along with question, links that you refereed it will save your question from getting downvoted

Comment: @gofor your welcome dear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

YES it's possible, the only concern that you have to watch for is that the CopyTo path should be the full path, not the relative one (ex: **c:\websites\myOtherFolder**).

this way, you can successfully copy/move the file from your ASP.NET code.

below is a pseudo code to show you how to get it done (assuming that the file has been placed on the root folder of your ASP.NET Application).

```
 using System.IO;
    ..
    ..
    ..



// Get the current app path:
var currentApplicationPath =  HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;

//Get the full path of the file    
var fullFilePath = currentApplicationPath + fileNameWithExtension;

// Get the destination path
var copyToPath = "This has to be the full path to your destination directory. 
                  Example d:\myfolder";

// Copy the file
File.Copy(fullFilePath , copyToPath );
```

Answer (score 1):

use this function:

```
System.IO.File.Copy(FileToCopy, NewCopy)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to move file from one folder to other folder. you can change the file name while moving...

```
           string Tranfiles, ProcessedFiles;

           //Tranfiles = Server.MapPath(@"~\godurian\sth100\transfiles\" + Filename);

           Tranfiles = Server.MapPath(@"~\transfiles\" + Filename);
           if (File.Exists(Server.MapPath(@"~\transfiles\" + Filename)))
           {
               File.Delete(Server.MapPath(@"~\transfiles\" + Filename));
           }

           //ProcessedFiles = Server.MapPath(@"~\godurian\sth100\ProcessedFiles");
           ProcessedFiles = Server.MapPath(@"~\ProcessedFiles");

           File.Move(Tranfiles, ProcessedFiles);
```

That's it now you can check your application folder to confirm the move process status